# Error: expected primary expression before '.' token

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a code to check the bracket pairs in an input string and print out either "Success" (for an input with matched pair) or the the 1-based index of the first unmatched closing bracket.

However I'm getting an error:

> expected primary expression before '.' token

when I compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <string>

struct Bracket {
    Bracket(char type, int position):
        type(type),
        position(position)
    {}

    bool Matchc(char c) {
        if (type == '[' && c == ']')
            return true;
        if (type == '{' && c == '}')
            return true;
        if (type == '(' && c == ')')
            return true;
        return false;

    }

    char type;
    int position;
};


int main() {
    std::string text;
    getline(std::cin, text);
    int z;

    std::stack <Bracket> opening_brackets_stack;
    for (int position = 0; position < text.length(); ++position) {
        char next = text[position];

        if (next == '(' || next == '[' || next == '{') {
            opening_brackets_stack.push(Bracket(next,0));
        }

        if (next == ')' || next == ']' || next == '}') {

            if(Bracket.Matchc(next) == false || opening_brackets_stack.empty() == false)
            {
               z = position;
            }

            else
            {
                opening_brackets_stack.pop();
            }

        }
    }

    if (opening_brackets_stack.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "Success";
    }

    else
    {
        std::cout << z;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `Bracket.Matchc(next)` - Bracket is a *type*. You need an *object* for that to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reason -** You are directly using the class `Bracket` instead of an object.

**Solution -**

To create an object, you need to include the following code in your program.

i.e..

In your `main`, include the following statement to create an object of Bracket.

```
Bracket brackObj(next, 0);
```

Now, include this particular object in the `stack`

```
if (next == '(' || next == '[' || next == '{') {
    opening_brackets_stack.push(brackObj);
}
```

And now, you can call your method `Matchc` on the same object.

```
if(brackObj.Matchc(next) == false ......
```

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to create an object for the class Bracket. Thanks a lot for helping me out! :)